# How to use tabs with separate controllers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my Angular 1.3 project I have the following:

```
<tabset>
  <tab ng-controller="FirstTabCtrl">
    {{content}}
  </tab>
  <tab ng-controller=SecondTabCtrl">
    {{content}}
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

In Angular 1.4.4 I get the following error message:

> Multiple directives [ngController, tab] asking for new/isolated scope

I have tried wrapping the tabs in div's but that destroys the layout.

How can rewrite the code to work with 1.4.4?

Here is a plunker describing the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/KScdI2jAZ4BAvDL4kCfk?p=preview

Comment: shouldn't you use routes and states to apply controllers if you have a tabbed app?

Comment: We are using the controllers in the state as one showed below.
.state('tab.first', {
    url: '/first',
    cache: false,
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/tab-first.html',
        controller: 'FirstCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

Comment: I don't want to change the url based on which tab is selected. The page has several tabsets.

Answer (score 1):

If you definitely don't want to use routes and states to handle the tabs, you could restructure the content *inside* each tab directive: add the ng-controller to a div inside the <**tab**> element, like this:

```
<tab heading="tab 1">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        {{content}}
    </div>
</tab>
```

Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YzZ83tgHbgSEk7Twjkio) to show it.
This doesn't destroy the tab layout, but if it does in some way, you can always handle that with CSS.

Comment: If I can have a solution with with state and several tabsets, I'm open to that.